# cvitem, cvline alignment

Tags: moderncv, cv

Here is my command :

```
\newpage

\cvitem{$\rhd$}{\small{\textbf{Xxxxxxx}}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Yyyyyyyyyyyyy}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Zzzzzzzzzzzzz}}

\cvitem{$\rhd$}{\small{\textbf{Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee}}
```

Minimum code to compile :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{soul}% http://ctan.org/pkg/soul
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\textbf\textsc}

\usepackage[inner=1.2cm,outer=1.2cm,top=0.9cm,bottom=0.9cm]{geometry}

\firstname{\Large{AAAA}}
\familyname{\Large{\textsc{CCCC}}}
\title{\small \textcolor{light-gray}{\textbf{CCCCC} }}
\address{\textbf{CCCCC}}{\textbf{CCCCC}}  
\mobile{\textbf{CCCC}}             
\email{CCCC@aol.fr} 
\extrainfo{\textbf{CCC}}  


\renewcommand*{\emaillink}[2][]{
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
{\textbf{\href{mailto:#2}{#2}}}
{\textbf{\href{mailto:#2}{#1}}}}

\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}{\marvosymbol{66}}


\begin{document}

\cvitem{$\rhd$}{\small{\textbf{Xxxxxxx}}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Yyyyyyyyyyyyy}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Zzzzzzzzzzzzz}}

\cvitem{$\rhd$}{\small{\textbf{Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}}}
\cvline{-}       {\small{Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee}}


\end{document}
```

Result :

[image: abelFirstTry]

But I would like second cvline to be next to firt one e.g. something like that :

[image: abelWantedOutput]

How could I do this simply ?

Notes : after some tries, it seems the following (see "Mini page" codes) is what I would need but how could I automatically adjust text on the right ? I would like text not to overlap amrgins and to adapt to mini page.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{soul}% http://ctan.org/pkg/soul
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\textbf\textsc}

\usepackage[inner=1.2cm,outer=1.2cm,top=0.9cm,bottom=0.9cm]{geometry}

\firstname{\Large{AAAA}}
\familyname{\Large{\textsc{CCCC}}}
\title{\small \textcolor{light-gray}{\textbf{CCCCC} }}
\address{\textbf{CCCCC}}{\textbf{CCCCC}}  
\mobile{\textbf{CCCC}}             
\email{CCCC@aol.fr} 
\extrainfo{\textbf{CCC}}  


\renewcommand*{\emaillink}[2][]{
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
{\textbf{\href{mailto:#2}{#2}}}
{\textbf{\href{mailto:#2}{#1}}}}

\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}{\marvosymbol{66}}


\begin{document}

\cvitem{$\rhd$}{\small{\textbf{Xxxxxxx}}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Yyyyyyyyyyyyy}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Zzzzzzzzzzzzz}}

\cvitem{$\rhd$}{\small{\textbf{Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}}}
\cvline{-}      {\small{Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee}}

\vspace{4cm}

%Mini page ?

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\textwidth}
\cvitem{$\rhd$}{\small{\textbf{Xxxxxxx}}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Yyyyyyyyyyyyy}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Zzzzzzzzzzzzz}}
\end{minipage} \hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
\cvitem{$\rhd$}{\small{\textbf{Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee}}
\end{minipage}



\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) And as always: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I think I would need something like mini page.

Comment: Anyone would have a suggestion ?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [moderncv: How to control the length of cvitems and cvlines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325610/110998), where @abel asked more or less the same, and where the solution seems to cover this issue?

Comment: So, now. Why are you asking a question twice? Now two people provided a similar answer to the same problem, making one contribution useless and a loss of time. And i am sad to say it was my time. That is not how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are using `moderncv` for the completely wrong reasons. It is a ready made style, no need to change it. If you don't like the style, you shouldn't use it working hard to change the style. It is not worth the effort. Joseph Wright wrote a series of tips and hints to quickly set up a CV from scratch. [Writing a curriculum vitae in LaTeX](http://www.texdev.net/2011/11/05/writing-a-curriculum-vitae-in-latex-part-1/)

Following a redefnition of `cvitem` and `cvline` (the later is obsolete with current `moderncv`) to do what i think you want it to do.

[image: abelModerncv]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\textbf\textsc}

\usepackage[inner=1.2cm,outer=1.2cm,top=0.9cm,bottom=0.9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\textbf\textsc}

\usepackage[inner=1.2cm,outer=1.2cm,top=0.9cm,bottom=0.9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}

\colorlet{light-gray}{gray!20!white}
\firstname{\Large{AAAA}}
\familyname{\Large{\textsc{CCCC}}}
\title{\small \textcolor{light-gray}{\textbf{CCCCC} }}
\address{\textbf{CCCCC}}{\textbf{CCCCC}}  
\mobile{\textbf{CCCC}}             
\email{CCCC@aol.fr} 
\extrainfo{\textbf{CCC}}  


\renewcommand*{\emaillink}[2][]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
    {\textbf{\href{mailto:#2}{#2}}}
    {\textbf{\href{mailto:#2}{#1}}}}

    \renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}{\marvosymbol{66}}


    \begin{document}
    \makecvtitle

    \cvitem{$\rhd$}{Xxxxxxx}
    \cvline{-}{Yangtse Yoga Yeast}
    \cvline{-}{Zzzzzzzzzzzzz}

    \cvitem{$\rhd$}{Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
    \cvline{-}{busy bee on a big pile of blue butter cups}
    \cvline{-}{Cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
    \cvline{-}{Dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd}
    \cvline{-}{Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee}

    \vspace{2cm}


    \renewcommand{\cvitem}[2]{\parbox[t]{1.5em}{$\rhd$}{\raggedright\small\bfseries#2\par}\vspace{1ex}}
    \renewcommand{\cvline}[2]{\parbox[t]{1.5em}{--}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em}{\raggedright\small#2}\par\vspace{.5ex}}
    \fbox{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \cvitem{}{X-ray Stingray whale}
        \cvline{}{Yangtse Yoga Yeast}
        \cvline{}{Zebra, Gnu and Lion}
    \end{minipage}}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
        \cvitem{}{Ants are strong little animals}
        \cvline{}{Busy bee on a big pile of blue butter cups busy bee on a big pile of blue butter cups busy bee on a big pile of blue butter cups }
        \cvline{}{Capybaras are crazy but somehow cute}
        \cvline{}{Ducks are just lovely}
        \cvline{}{Eeeeeeeeeek, a scorpion. One, two, three, for, five, six, seven, eight legs. Hi arachnophobia}
    \end{minipage}



    \end{document}
```