# moderncv: How to control the length of cvitems and cvlines?

Tags: minipage, moderncv

See code :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{soul}% http://ctan.org/pkg/soul
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\textbf\textsc}

\usepackage[inner=1.2cm,outer=1.2cm,top=0.9cm,bottom=0.9cm]{geometry}

\firstname{\Large{AAAA}}
\familyname{\Large{\textsc{CCCC}}}
\title{\small \textcolor{light-gray}{\textbf{CCCCC} }}
\address{\textbf{CCCCC}}{\textbf{CCCCC}}  
\mobile{\textbf{CCCC}}             
\email{CCCC@aol.fr} 
\extrainfo{\textbf{CCC}}  


\renewcommand*{\emaillink}[2][]{
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
{\textbf{\href{mailto:#2}{#2}}}
{\textbf{\href{mailto:#2}{#1}}}}

\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}{\marvosymbol{66}}


\begin{document}

\cvitem{$\rhd$}{\small{\textbf{Xxxxxxx}}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Yyyyyyyyyyyyy}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Zzzzzzzzzzzzz}}

\cvitem{$\rhd$}{\small{\textbf{Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}}}
\cvline{-}      {\small{Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee}}

\vspace{4cm}

%Mini page ?

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\textwidth}
\cvitem{$\rhd$}{\small{\textbf{Xxxxxxx}}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Yyyyyyyyyyyyy}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Zzzzzzzzzzzzz}}
\end{minipage} \hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
\cvitem{$\rhd$}{\small{\textbf{Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd}}
\cvline{-}{\small{Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee}}
\end{minipage}



\end{document}
```

What I want to do is what you see after `%Mini Page ?` but as you can see some text goes outside page margin. How could I adapt it automatically (go to the next line) ?

Comment: Tell LaTeX where some long words can be hyphenated.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Then how would you do this ?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27890/how-to-add-global-hyphenation-rules]

Comment: `\Large\textbf\textsc` is the same as `\Large\textbf{\textsc}` it can't possibly work can it? shouldn't this be `Large\bfseries\scshape` ?

Comment: font size commands do not take an argument `\small{\textbf{Xxxxxxx}}` is the same as `\small\textbf{Xxxxxxx}`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\cvline` and `\cvitem` have a fixed width. If you put them into a small `minipage`, all you get are overfull hboxes, but the lines keep their width. This means that you have to adjust the width of `\cvline` and `\cvitem` to achieve what you want. Put the following definition into your preamble:

```
\newenvironment{minicv}[2][60.37605pt]%
 {\begin{minipage}[t]{#2}%
  \maincolumnwidth=#2%
  \hintscolumnwidth=#1%
  \advance\maincolumnwidth-\hintscolumnwidth
  \advance\maincolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth
 }%
 {\end{minipage}%
 }
```

Now you can write in your document:

```
\begin{minicv}{5cm}
  \cvline{-}{\small This is the text. Usually you don't have to care
      about hyphenation. If you notice that TeX doesn't know about a
      certain hy\-phe\-na\-tion point that it should use, insert it
      using back\-slash mi\-nus like shown in the source code of
      this text.}
  \cvline{-}{Another CV item.}
\end{minicv}
```

The `minicv` environment has an optional argument for adjusting the width of the first column that contains the item markers. `\begin{minicv}[1cm]{5cm}` sets the width of the first column to 1cm.

After this change you will be able to put stacks of `\cvline`s side by side, but you will discover, that they are not top-aligned, even though `minipage` is used with the option `t`. The reason is that `\cvline` and `\cvitem` are implemented as a `tabular` that is centered, not top-aligned. To fix  this, put the following two lines into your preamble.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cvitem}{\begin{tabular}}{\begin{tabular}[t]}{}{}
```

Comment: Seems i have completely wasted my time with the other answer :-) Especially looking at the OPs profile and the last active date.