# Stacking lists for CVs

Tags: vertical-alignment, lists, itemize

I am currently writing my academic CV and listing a few details. Only problem is there is a huge amount of whitespace to the right (since the lists in question only have a few words for each bullet point). Is there any way I can stack lists? So, for example I can have List 1 with 4 points, then to the right of that is list 2 with 3 points.

Comment: See the post [moderncv: How to control the length of cvitems and cvlines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325630). It seems to solve your problem.

Comment: @gernot are you sure?  It's not obvious to me that this is a `moderncv` question.

Comment: @DaiBowen Yes, you are right, my fault.

Comment: Hi John, please provide a small document that compiles and that shows us your context.

Comment: There are many different ways to do this. At this point, however, we don't even know what format you are using. Is it some form of 'plain' TeX, ConTeXt, LaTeX? And if LaTeX, then we're still missing a lot of information? Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: Having fiddled about with this (in `moderncv`) I ended up not bothering as each list seemed to have 1 (or occasionally more) longer item which would then wrap (with any reasonable gutter between the columns you end up with *very* short items.  Tweaking the wording to have items like "Analysis of complex data sets, including developing appropriate software" instead of one item for the development and one for the analysis can help.  You may of course prefer a punchier style in some situations -- with more detail this could be a very interesting question.